# Preventing page break after title page

Tags: titles, article

I am trying to create a title page for my thesis proposal, which is using the article class.  I have the page formatted correctly, but it does not act like the default article title page where the document starts on the title page.  Instead, I get the body of the proposal starting on the second page, which is not what I want.  Also, it is not sufficient to just put the abstract on the title page; the first section should also start on the title page if there is room.

Here is my code right now:

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        {\LARGE Insert Title Here \par}
        \vskip 2em
        A Master's Thesis Proposal \\
        {\tiny by} \\
        Christopher J. Lieb \\
        \vskip 2em
        Thesis Advisor \par
        Professor Gary Pollice \par
        \vskip 1em
        Reader\\
        {\Large \makebox[3in]{\hrulefill} \par}
        \vskip 1em
        {\small
            \today \\
            Department of Computer Science\\
            Worcester Polytechnic Institute\\
            100 Institute Road\\
            Worcester, MA  01609\\}
    \end{center}
    \par
\end{titlepage}
```

I am just inserting it right at the beginning of my document environment.  I started this from the article.cls where I thought the title page was being created, but apparently I missed the part that gets rid of the page break.

How do I make the document start on the title page like the article class does?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of the `titlepage` environment that you get a separate title *page*? Just remove the environment if you don't want that behaviour?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply redefining `\endtitlepage` in the preamble would be sufficient:

```
\let\endtitlepage\relax
```

Comment: Wouldn't *Don't use `titlepage`* be cleaner and more to the point? This is the kind of hack that works, but is hard to understand for newcommers and is more of the kind *quick and dirty*.

Answer (score 3):

Figures that I'd get it AFTER I posted the question.

```
...

    % prevent a page break from being put at the end of the title page so that 
            % the contents of the paper spill onto the title page
    % save the function of the \newpage macro so we can restore it later
    \global\let\newpagegood\newpage
    \global\let\newpage\relax
\end{titlepage}
% restore the \newpage command after creating the title page
\global\let\newpage\newpagegood
```