# Adding more items on tex article title section

Tags: titles, article

This is what I have at the head of my tex document (article):

```
\title{Some Article}
\author{John Doe}

\date{\today}

\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[textwidth=16cm,textheight=24cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
. . .
```

I want to add a subtext below the title. As shown in the [practical example given here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation) I want to have the author's name on the left  side, and supervisor's name on the right side. How can I do it? I tried the example from the above link, but, while compiling, it shows the error: `document begin is not specified`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own title page using the `titlepage` environment (as shown by the linked page you posted). One important thing to note is that it replaces the `\maketitle` command, i.e. it has to be placed after the `\begin{document}` not before. I think this is your problem.

Also for articles you would need to disable the page break at the end of the `titlepage` environment (See also [Preventing page break after title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3639/2975)).

Here some working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[textwidth=16cm,textheight=24cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{5cm}%
        {\huge The Title}\\[1cm]
        {\Large The SubTitle}\\[1cm]
        %...
    \end{center}
    \let\newpage\relax% Avoid following page break
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```