# Title sub-sections for a \documentclass{article}

Tags: titles, article

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding more items on tex article title section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14556/adding-more-items-on-tex-article-title-section)
>   [Subtitle with the \maketitle page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50182/subtitle-with-the-maketitle-page)

How can I specify a specify a "sub-title" in my title (\maketitle) page? By sub-title I mean something like a hierarchical child of a title, think "relationship between \section and \subsection", obviously smaller in font size but still looking as part of the title (e.g. "Bananas in the Savanna" "Cropping crap changes the genome of the biome"). Crap = natural fertiliser.

Comment: Another really closely related question: [\subtitle doesn't work in article document class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5948)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such a case I would prefer the `\titlepage` environment which gives me the freedom to design it in anyway I want to. Or you can also use the `scrartcl` `documentclass`  instead of `article` which supports the `\subtitle` command.

Comment: I don't know how to use the \titlepage environment in this way, could you kindly explain I would do that, please?