# How to include abstract into titlepage?

Tags: koma-script, titles, abstract

I don't want to have the abstract on a separate page but rather under the title. Also I then want to end the page and don't begin with the actual document.

This is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,abstracton,titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\titlehead{University}
\title{Title}
\subject{Subject}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}

\newpage

\tableofcontents
...    
\end{document}
```

I tried to use `\let\endtitlepage\relax` which was suggested in [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3639/preventing-page-break-after-title-page) but it doesn't change anything.

If I don't use titlepage then it's not centered vertically which I understand because the document is supposed to start right after it.

So, how can I get this layout without creating a custom titlepage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could misuse the `\publishers` element:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,abstracton,titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\titlehead{University}
\title{Title}
\subject{Subject}
\author{Author}

\publishers{%
    \normalfont\normalsize%
    \parbox{0.8\linewidth}{%
        Your abstarct Text. Your abstarct Text. Your abstarct Text. 
        Your abstarct Text. Your abstarct Text. Your abstarct Text. 
        Your abstarct Text. Your abstarct Text.
    }
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Since it’s value normally is centered an in `\Large` you have to put in it a `\parbox` of the desired width and set the font back to `\normalsize` (the `\normalfont` is a little superfluous here but does no harm at all).

[image: result]

If this doesn’t fits your needs on can redefine `{abstract}` and `\maketitle` to let the first collect and store it’s contest and the latter print out the content. But this would be an equal effort as making the title page manually. And only gainful if you need this in more than one or two documents …

### Update

**How to misuse the `\date` field to make the abstract appear higher on the page?**

```
\date{%
    \today% thats the default I guess
    \\[2\baselineskip]% Space between date and abstract
    \normalfont\normalsize%
    \parbox{0.8\linewidth}{%
        Your abstarct Text. Your abstarct Text. Your abstarct Text. 
        Your abstarct Text. Your abstarct Text. Your abstarct Text. 
        Your abstarct Text. Your abstarct Text.
    }
}
```

There’s only the little problem that the argument of `\date` can‘t contain paragraphs (i.e. blank lines or `\par`) so we must use `\\[<dim>]` to get a new line an insert some space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's indeed a way to go. But what annoys me a bit is that the text is too far at the bottom. Usually it's placed directly after the date. On the other hand I don't have any example for that at the moment.

Comment: @neo Since the date is a text filed too, you can use ist in the same way as `\publishers`. See my edit.

Comment: Ok that seems to work quite well. Thanks for your hack! It's greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 20):

Without abusing the usual commands, you can redefine `abstract` and patch the `\maketitle` command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage]{scrartcl}

\newsavebox{\abstractbox}
\renewenvironment{abstract}
  {\begin{lrbox}{0}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
   \begin{center}\normalfont\sectfont\abstractname\end{center}\quotation}
  {\endquotation\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
   \global\setbox\abstractbox=\box0 }

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\maketitle\endcsname
  {\vskip\z@\@plus3fill}
  {\vskip\z@\@plus2fill\box\abstractbox\vskip\z@\@plus1fill}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\titlehead{University}
\title{Title}
\subject{Subject}
\author{Author}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

You can play with the line

```
  {\vskip\z@\@plus2fill\box\abstractbox\vskip\z@\@plus1fill}
```

changing `2fill` and `1fill` till the result is pleasing.

The strategy is to save the abstract's typeset contents in a box for later use; the method with `lrbox` is rather standard; the only subtle point is to *globally* save the box, as we are doing the business inside the `abstract` environment. So the abstract is typeset in box register 0 and then the register `\abstractbox` is globally loaded with what's in `\box0`.

Where do you want it? Just between the `\date` and `\publishers` fields in the title page; so I looked at the code of `\maketitle` and found that between the two fields the code is

```
\vskip\z@\@plus3fill
```

(leave a flexible vertical space). With the help of `etoolbox` I change that code into

```
\vskip\z@\@plus2fill\box\abstractbox\vskip\z@\@plus1fill
```

so the previously saved box is typeset there, separated from the `\date` and `\publisher` fields by flexible vertical space.

Of course, the `abstract` environment must go *before* `\maketitle`. The code for typesetting the abstract itself is taken from the definition in `scrartcl.cls`, which basically puts "Abstract" (in the font used for section headings) centered above the text, which in turn is in a `quotation` environment.

---

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, I just refreshed the page and saw your answer after I accepted the other one. I like your solution very much, +1 for it. Although it's even more voodoo for me ^^

Comment: @neo I added some explanations for the code, hoping it's less like voodoo and more like white magic. :)

Comment: Thanks for your magical explanations! I understood most of it, of course not every command, but then you also just copy-pasted a bit :P I think tex-answers need a lot more explanations just like yours! Please keep that up, and have a nice day :)

Comment: +1 for not abusing other commands. This feels more in the spirit of *TeX anyway. :-)

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this without using `scrartcl`?

Answer (score 6):

You could also use the `notitlepage` option instead of `titlepage` option.

That is, change 
the first line

`\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,abstracton,titlepage]{scrartcl}`

of your document to

`\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,abstracton,notitlepage]{scrartcl}`.

Then your code produces the following output.

[image]

Comment: Well, notitlepage is the default for scrartcl and I especially want the layout like in titlepage (which is more vertically centered)

Answer (score 1):

You could just define a titlepage layout...example template given [in this file](http://www.howtotex.com/download/titlepage-howtotex.tex) and adapt to your own needs....