# How to include abstract into titlepage (variant)?

Tags: titles, abstract

I am facing a problem similar to this post:

[How to include abstract into titlepage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40518/how-to-include-abstract-into-titlepage)

where I would like to include the abstract in the title page. This I managed thanks to the post #8. However,the journal format requires the abstract to be in-between authors's name and address... and this is where I could not find a simple solution by moving around the key command

```
\vskip\z@\@plus2fill\box\abstractbox\vskip\z@\@plus1fill
```

and this is where I reach my limits too...

Could anyone come with a workaround for this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) There's no need to add a thanks to your questions or answers. The preferred way to express thanks is through upvoting answers that help you.

Comment: You can try to misuse the author field to insert abstract.

Comment: Maybe `\author{Me\footnote{My street 1, 1A2 3B4 My town}}` ?

Comment: Intriguing arrangement, which journal is this?

Comment: Wildlife Biology, a small journal for applied research in ecology

Answer (score 1):

You may fake the title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  {\LARGE My Title}\vspace{3ex}

  {\large My Name}\footnote{some remark}
\end{center}\bigskip

\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}\bigskip

\begin{center}
  {\large MyAdress}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well that's one option, but the last one for me. The reason is that I do have several style files, all based on the same structure and variables (authors, address, abstract). If the paper is resubmitted elsewhere then all I have to do is to change the line calling for the style and the paper is re-formatted. With this solution, I have to fake all environments and so on, don't you think?