# Logo in a syllabus

Tags: logos

I am trying to modify a syllabus I found on internet. In particular, I would like to include some logos before the Course name and description. My MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,headheight=3ex,headsep=3ex]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\newcommand{\blankline}{\quad\pagebreak[2]}

\title{Course Code: Course Title}
\author{Instructor name}
\date{Semester, Year}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[mmddyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage{advdate}
\newdateformat{syldate}{\twodigit{\THEMONTH}/\twodigit{\THEDAY}}
\newsavebox{\MONDAY}\savebox{\MONDAY}{Mon}
\newcommand{\week}[1]{
  \paragraph*{\kern-2ex\quad #1, \syldate{\today} - \AdvanceDate[4]\syldate{\today}:}
  \ifdim\wd1=\wd\MONDAY
    \AdvanceDate[7]
  \else
    \AdvanceDate[7]
  \fi
}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\usepackage{url}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{layout}

\lhead{}
\chead{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\rhead{\footnotesize Text in header}


\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\small \thepage/\pageref*{LastPage}}
\rfoot{}

\usepackage{array, xcolor}
\usepackage{color,hyperref}
\definecolor{clemsonorange}{HTML}{EA6A20}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,linkcolor=clemsonorange,urlcolor=clemsonorange,anchorcolor=clemsonorange,citecolor=black}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.17\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-a.png}
\end{flushleft} 
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.66\textwidth}\centering
{\bfseries Ph.D. in Economics, Management \& Statistics}\par
\medskip
{\bfseries University of A \& University of B}\par
\medskip
\end{minipage}
\medskip
\begin{minipage}{.17\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-b.png}
\end{flushright} 
\end{minipage}

\maketitle



\begin{tabular*}{.93\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lr}


E-mail: \texttt{username@ncsu.edu} & Web: \href{www4.ncsu.edu/~username}{\tt\bf www4.ncsu.edu/~username}  \\

 Office Hours: M 10-11:45am  &  Class Hours: T/Th 3-4:15pm \\

 Office: ... & Class Room: ... \\
 & \\
Lab Room: ... & Lab Hours: W 3-5pm \\
&  \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}

\vspace{5 mm}


\section*{Course Description}

Bla bla bla ...

\bigskip

\noindent New paragraph. Bla bla bla ...


\section*{Required Materials}

\begin{itemize}
\item Course notes available on Moodle. Books. Tech. Bla bla bla ...
\end{itemize}

\section*{Prerequisites/Corequisites}
Prerequisites: MA 116, ... .  Corequisites: ... .

\section*{Course Objectives}
Successful students:
\begin{enumerate}
\item ...
\item ...
\item ...
\item ...
\item ...
\item ...
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

However, the logos and the names of the Universities appear in a separate page. Instead, I would like to have them just before the Course Title. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,headheight=3ex,headsep=3ex]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\newcommand{\blankline}{\quad\pagebreak[2]}

\title{Course Code: Course Title}
\author{Instructor name}
\date{Semester, Year}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[mmddyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage{advdate}
\newdateformat{syldate}{\twodigit{\THEMONTH}/\twodigit{\THEDAY}}
\newsavebox{\MONDAY}\savebox{\MONDAY}{Mon}
\newcommand{\week}[1]{
  \paragraph*{\kern-2ex\quad #1, \syldate{\today} - \AdvanceDate[4]\syldate{\today}:}
  \ifdim\wd1=\wd\MONDAY
    \AdvanceDate[7]
  \else
    \AdvanceDate[7]
  \fi
}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\usepackage{url}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{layout}

\lhead{}
\chead{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\rhead{\footnotesize Text in header}


\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\small \thepage/\pageref*{LastPage}}
\rfoot{}

\usepackage{array, xcolor}
\usepackage{color,hyperref}
\definecolor{clemsonorange}{HTML}{EA6A20}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,linkcolor=clemsonorange,urlcolor=clemsonorange,anchorcolor=clemsonorange,citecolor=black}


\let\endtitlepage\relax % Preventing page break after title page https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3639/preventing-page-break-after-title-page

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\makeatletter
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.17\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-a.png}
\end{flushleft} 
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.66\textwidth}\centering
{\bfseries Ph.D. in Economics, Management \& Statistics}\par
\medskip
{\bfseries University of A \& University of B}\par
\medskip
\end{minipage}
\medskip
\begin{minipage}{.17\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-b.png}
\end{flushright} 
\end{minipage}
   \begin{center}
      \Large\textbf{\@title}\\
      \large\textit{\@author}
   \end{center}
   \makeatother
\begin{tabular*}{.93\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lr}


E-mail: \texttt{username@ncsu.edu} & Web: \href{www4.ncsu.edu/~username}{\tt\bf www4.ncsu.edu/~username}  \\

 Office Hours: M 10-11:45am  &  Class Hours: T/Th 3-4:15pm \\

 Office: ... & Class Room: ... \\
 & \\
Lab Room: ... & Lab Hours: W 3-5pm \\
&  \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{titlepage}

\vspace{5 mm}


\section*{Course Description}

Bla bla bla ...

\bigskip

\noindent New paragraph. Bla bla bla ...


\section*{Required Materials}

\begin{itemize}
\item Course notes available on Moodle. Books. Tech. Bla bla bla ...
\end{itemize}

\section*{Prerequisites/Corequisites}
Prerequisites: MA 116, ... .  Corequisites: ... .

\section*{Course Objectives}
Successful students:
\begin{enumerate}
\item ...
\item ...
\item ...
\item ...
\item ...
\item ...
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]